# Group items in a list by two’s — Python

Tags: python, list, grouping

Say I’ve got a list

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And I’d like to get this result:

```
res = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

What’s the cleanest way to go about this?

Comment: ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[[ls[2*i],ls[2*i+1]] for i in range(len(ls)//2)]

Comment: For those who's here to get the answer yet facing long outdated duplicate link above -  I think I'd say best answer for this case would be `iterator = iter(ls)` and then `list(zip(iterator, iterator))` - gives list of tuples though. One liner for Python3.8+ would be `list(zip(iterator := iter(ls), iterator))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of the `zip` call, which allows you to group lists.  So, something like:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
res = list(zip(ls[::2], ls[1::2]))
```

should do the trick.

`ls[::2]` extracts all the even-numbered list items (I say this because index 0 is "even"). And `ls[1::2]` grabs all the odd-numbered list items. Then the `zip` call pairs them off like you want.

Be aware that `zip` can take more than two lists, as well. Have a look at the online docs to get more info. Also, in Py2, the `zip` call returned a list (I believe), but in Py3 it returns a zip object, which you can cast as a list to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```py
res = [ls[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(ls),2)]
```